# Curious User Activity

Tags: discussion, users, deleted-users

I've seen [this screen name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4935216/ananad-ms) on at least 3 different occasions and on each occasion, the account had never been more than a day old. While it's not out of the realm of possibility that each instance I'd seen was a completely different person, but the odds seem quite long to me.

I ask now because on the previous occasions, the user had asked somewhat pointless, downvote-magnet questions (and didn't appear to provide meaningful feedback in comments or answers) and it's kind of stuck with me, about this specific handle... and here this person is, *again*, with another head-scratcher (and not in a fun way). This kind of user is a bit of an irritation to me especially, because I get the "user deleted" notification every now and then.

Is there a way to confirm that there's an OP creating throwaway accounts (for whatever reason)?

Comment: Looks like you're right. Try google **"Ananad Ms" site:stackoverflow.com**. Here's a few examples: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4917021/ananad-ms http://stackoverflow.com/users/4880772/ananad-ms http://stackoverflow.com/users/4844620/ananad-ms

Comment: Brilliant @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå . I can't imagine what the chap's playing at here, with all the throwaway accounts. Is this something to call Mod's attention to? I don't care much for hit-and-run askers, who can't even be bothered to ask decent questions

Comment: If you suspect that: *1)* It's a dupe account created to circumvent a question ban. And *2)* The user have not learned from their mistakes; keeps posting crap. Then **yes**, you should definitely flag it for mod attention. Just make sure that you thoroughly explains what you've observed and link to the other accounts.

Comment: "Ananad" is a mistype of "Anand", a very common Hindi name.  Which lets you find the [other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4771577/anand-ms) he used before.  Users like that create new accounts to bypass a question ban, the system has no solid protection against that.  OpenID sucks, it only works if a user has an interest in re-using an account.  SO would probably be a much better place if users had to wait 24 hours after creating an account before they can ask.

Comment: Good find @HansPassant. The latest incarnation has been flagged for mods to sort out. The profile you linked to is just a trove of gravity-bait

Comment: Is the possible for moderators to perform an IP ban?

Comment: @merlin2011: It is possible. Whether that is the correct course of action in this specific case will be up to the mods.

Comment: @merlin2011 An IP ban won't do that much, especially if he's using a dynamic IP.

Comment: also, an ip ban could possibly hit another user on the same gsteway at a future point - slim chance I know, but still possible

Comment: If one were an idiot, you could almost admire the dedication to the same username; The reason this caught my eye was because I remembered the name. If the user had mustered even a little bit of creativity, he might have gotten away with it

Comment: Primefaces that's a awful lot of tag-in-title. Primefaces it's hard to resist the urge to go on an editing spree.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are some relatively new measures in place to try to [prevent question-ban recidivism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-recidivism-system), but they're not particularly aggressive. Unfortunately, it's an open secret that it's not hard to work around these measures by creating new accounts. I strongly believe that tightening this down will lead to a dramatic improvement in incoming question quality, but I understand why Stack Exchange wants to make sure we don't suffer from false positives as they tune this.

If you see a user who appears to be creating a series of accounts to work around a question ban (like this person), flag these accounts as they appear and we'll deal with them. We have a means of gradually blocking their ability to create and post from these new accounts (which we've applied here). I've found that to be very effective in stopping the worst question-ban evaders.

Comment: If that type of user is question banned, what happens to any open questions they have at the time? Are those questions automatically closed/deleted?

Comment: @Leigh - If we delete the accounts and apply the measures described above, normal account deletion rules apply. Downvoted posts will be deleted by the system on deletion of the account, but posts with 0 or higher net votes will be left behind.

Comment: So in theory they could still be rewarded by getting answers to some of their questions anyway, if the questions are still open :/