# Can we rename the discussion tag to something less misleading?

Tags: feature-request

So I just had [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302162/who-are-team-profile) promptly deleted. I think my mistake was that I was trying to have a discussion about something, which I thought was OK as 25% of the suggested tags are called "discussion".

First off, can I get some clarification on what is an acceptable "discussion"? It may be that I am just misunderstanding and there are valid and non-valid discussions.

Though assuming it's not generally acceptable, then perhaps we should consider renaming the tag to be less misleading? I don't know what we should rename it to though, I guess that's open to, erm... debate

Comment: The fact that Meta has a [meta-tag:discussion] tag, doesn't mean the discussion doesn't have to be constructive. The deleted question was quite a ramble, a moderator flag would've been sufficient.

Comment: I'm not not unsure what you are saying, I think perhaps one too many doesn't's for my brain to cope with ;)

Comment: Case in point: _"I don't know... I guess I'll just tag this one discussion, as feature requests never seem to go down well here."_ --> This isn't constructive.

Comment: @Cerbrus: That's a fair comment, but it's not like that was the whole post

Comment: I explained why I deleted that post; the answer is yes, the accounts were worth looking at, but Meta users cannot do much about that, that's a job for moderators. It has little to do with the tag you used. To protect innocent accounts from unnecessary vigilante persecution, I removed the post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is a perfectly fine tag for having open discussions with the community about issues impacting the site.

Your question wasn't deleted because it had a bad tag, it was deleted because there was nothing the community could do or say about it and moderators were already on the case. The only purpose leaving that question up would serve would be to publicly shame the user doing this. Unless there's a larger lesson to be learned by the community, we tend to remove Meta questions pointing out problems with specific users.

Custom flags tend to be the better way to communicate things like this, so that they don't become public spectacles.

We appreciate the heads-up and have acted on what you presented.

Comment: It could be argued that the community benefit might be that it exemplifies situations that should be flagged for attention. I would guess a lot of users are cautious about flagging as it can be difficult to know what can be flagged and what shouldn't be, having some examples of good flags, bad flags would be useful. But I don't want to argue it as it's not that significant in my opinion

Comment: @musefan: if there was a post that talked about cases in *hypothetical* or *general* terms, rather than point to a specific existing user that could well work, but when it comes to specific cases of suspected abuse, better to flag.

Comment: Hmm, you can't really publicly shame "profile 22".  Publicly shaming StackExchange for making it so easy to create 22 accounts to repeatedly bypass question bans surely is the sticking point?  Suppressing this isn't really okay, SO users have a right to know that their votes are pointless.

Comment: @HansPassant: Your attitude is exactly *why* the post needed to be deleted. Until proven guilty, you need to assume that the accounts were innocent. What if there was an in-joke to the name *profile 22* and had no relationship to other accounts using that name, for example?

Comment: Hmya, what if the repeated cursory evidence that creating new accounts to bypass question bans is very common turns out to be accurate?  If you don't want to disclose what you know, and you know the facts from at least the OP's question you deleted, then just say so, it is okay.  This attitude of "you're stoopid because you can't know the facts" is not okay.

Comment: @HansPassant: so you rather have we hang out the dirty laundry when we do our work? That's not going to fly. If you have concrete, constructive ideas about how to curb the problem you perceive to be there, feel free to post about that instead.

Comment: I already said it is okay to say that you don't want to disclose it.  I just don't think that intentionally hiding this problem is constructive in any way.  Deleting questions from SO users that want to table this problem is problematic, it is most certainly worth a discussion.  This affects everybody.

Comment: No one's intentionally hiding the fact that people creating question-ban evasion accounts are a huge problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300810/is-there-any-automation-to-detect-stop-shill-behaviour/300845#comment229512_300845 . I've even complained about this myself: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295283/19679 . If the point of the question had been how to detect and stop users like this, that would have been a discussion worth having. Instead, it was entirely focused on a single user who was dealt with as soon as we saw the flags on them.